# Keep Server alive for subsequent requests while using TCP connection in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am pretty new to Python Socket Programming.

I am trying to make a python server script using TCPHandler which accepting data send by something called as 'tracker'. tracker is sending continuous data & my server is also accepting it. however, sometime tracker send Null data. due to this, script stops receiving data.

after that i have to restart script to receive data.

here is my script.

```
class MyTCPhandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        if self.data:
            self.request.sendall(self.data)
            save_new_tracker_data(self.data)
        elif not self.data:
            logger.info("Black data string received")

class MultiThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, data):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        save_data(self.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import socket
    import threading

    models.database.connect()
    HOST, PORT = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 9999
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPhandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Thnx in Advance.